# Need help. How to create session after login with the user details in laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1

I want to save some details on session when the user login. And the details are retrieved from the same user table that user for Auth(). Do I have to query again after login and set the session variables or there is a way within auth.
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the currently logged in user with `Auth::user()`. So, if you wanted to store the user's username in the session after login you could do this:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
Session::put('username', $user->username);
```

Comment: if user logs out, then a long time, log in again, the session still exist?

Comment: No, the session will still expire based on your session expiration rules. But the session will be refilled next time they login.

Answer (score 1):

To store user information, You can easily use

```
    $user = Auth::User();
    Session::put('user', $user);
    $user=Session::get('user');
    return $user->name;
```

You must have to put `use Session;` in controller where you want to set or get the value

here `$user` is a object you can get all other property using this `->` sign.

Thank You